# Reading from asset in WebView

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview, assets

[image]

In my application I put my html file in asset folder. My html file includes photo, but when I run it, my photo can't be loaded. How to solve such problem?

Here is my code:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView wv;
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/b.html");

    }
    }
```

and I put b.html in my asset, but it shows me like this pi

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: You should indeed show the complete img tag.